Summing partially vs completely missing data in R
I have data that is sometimes partially missing and sometimes completely missing. If I sum the partially missing data, I would like to return the sum of the non-missing data, but if I sum the completely missing data, I would like to return a missing value.
I am using base R, but if there is a better solution using the tidyverse, I'm happy to use it.
Here are some examples of what happens when I use the na.rm option in R:
    > sum(c(1,NA,2), na.rm = "TRUE")
    [1] 3
    > sum(c(NA,NA,NA), na.rm = "TRUE")
    [1] 0
    > sum(c(1,NaN,2), na.rm = "TRUE")
    [1] 3
    > sum(c(NaN,NaN,NaN), na.rm = "TRUE")
    [1] 0

The sums of 3 for the partially missing data are what I want. The sum of zero for the completely missing data is not what I want. Is there a different function or option that I can use that will cause completely missing data to return a missing value?

You can create your own helper function:
my_sum <- function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x))) return(NA)
  sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}
my_sum(c(1, NA, 2)) ## 3
my_sum(c(NA,NA,NA)) ## NA
my_sum(c(1,NaN,2))  ## 3
my_sum(c(NaN,NaN,NaN)) ## NA

If you're being very particular you might want to return NA_real_ instead of NA. These values are printed the same, but the latter is of type logical; R will automatically coerce values to numeric as necessary, so this is probably an unnecessarily fussy point.
Related: Sum/return NA when all values are NA

Thanks. If I do that, will it be compatible with group_by, or will I lose the ability to group?

I don't see why it wouldn't be compatible with group_by. sum() and my_sum() are both functions that take a numeric vector, so they should? be interchangeable as far as tidyverse is concerned ...
